# R OOP CODE that return results from data set

Tags: r, oop

I am trying to work on a OOP code in R. The dataset I am using is something like bellow:

```
ID VISIT  ROOM TYPE  VALUE
3   0     bedroom     20
3   1     Office      11
3   1     bedroom     5
```

I need to write a code using OOP (S3, S4, or RC) in R creating a function 'subject' that would work on the following situations bellow:

```
##check if subject exists
out <- subject(x, 3)
print(out)
Subject ID: 3 

##summary by visit, room type on subject ID
 out <- subject(x, 3) %>% summary
 print(out)
ID:3    
visit bedroom  office
  0    20       NA
  1    5        11

## Show a summary of values
out <- subject(x, 3) %>% visit(0) %>% room("bedroom") %>% summary
print(out)
ID: 3 
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    3.0    27.0    40.0    20.8    70.0   200.0
```

I am not used to write in OOP so it is rather difficult for me. Any advice on how to start or example would be great.

Appreciate any help

Tks

Comment: [Hadley's OOP chapter](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html) is a decent starting point, though you may want to supplement it with [the R6 vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R6/vignettes/Introduction.html), as RC has been superseded. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27219132/4497050) also has some useful info. Generally it's probably a good idea to start with S3 due to its simplicity, though its flexibility may be frustrating for someone coming from a more formal OOP environment.

Comment: Tks for the info I am checking it